# Is there any good way to replace 'transition' below IE9?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to build a webpage using bunch of transitions without javascript.

What is the best way to accomplish this impossible-looking task efficiently?

My webpage has to provide complete support for IE9, unfortunately.

Comment: don't ask for best ways! please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve to ask better questions

Comment: CSS transitions are the simplest way to include transitions in a website, unfortunately they are not supported below IE10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fallback to JavaScript animations like [implemented by jQuery](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_animate.asp) if the browser doesn't support transition. The [modernizr library](https://modernizr.com/) can detect with transition is supported.

Alternatively you might go for [graceful degradation or progressive enhancement](https://www.w3.org/wiki/Graceful_degradation_versus_progressive_enhancement). This usually an accepted option, since it often cost a lot of developer resources to bring some trivial effects to a small portion of the user base.

As stated in the comments, what is a 'good way' depends on the specs of the project.